# How to compare pairs of values in column of SQL, for all possible pairs?

Tags: sql, postgresql

If anyone could help on this, it would be great! 
I work with version  `9.3` of `postgreSQL`.

I have one table (called `likes`) with three columns;

- trackurl
- userurl
- date

That is full of data, and another (now empty) table  (called `track2tracks`) with 4 columns ;

- track1
- track2
- date
- userurl

The key for table 'likes'  is `(trackurl, userurl, date)`.
The key for table `track2tracks` is `(track1, track2, date, userurl)`

I would like to fill the table `track2tracks` with all the combinations of tracks that are liked by the same user, showing the latest date of the two likes.

So far I understand that: I need to partition the like-table on userurl, and then for each user compare all the pairs of likes on their date. Then I  need to add these pairs (as track1 and track2) to the track2tracks-table, also adding the latest date and the corresponding user.

The biggest problem I have is how to compare values of pairs (of the same column; date).

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO track2tracks
  SELECT l1.trackurl, l2.trackurl, max(greatest(l1.date, l2.date)), l1.userurl
  FROM likes l1
  JOIN likes l2 ON (l1.userurl = l2.userurl) AND (l1.trackurl != l2.trackurl)
  GROUP BY l1.trackurl, l2.trackurl, l1.userurl;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Patrick!!!! This helped A LOT. 
I only had to delete self-edges (track1 = track2) and doubles (track1,track2) = (track2,track1) 
but apart from that this was superb!

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.